# Query builder conditional parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a user table that has related data on a belongsToMany basis

```
 users
    id
    first_name

 skills
    id
    name

 positions
    id
    name

 position_user
    position_id
    user_id
    created_at
    updated_at

 skill_user
   skill_id
   user_id
   created_at
   updated_at
```

In User model

```
public function positions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Position')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in Position

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

(the same for skills)

I am currently passing the following to a view:

```
$users = User::with('skills')
->with('skills')
->with('positions')
->get();
```

I want to be able to search on various combinations of skills and positions but am having difficulty creating an elegant solution.

If I select a position or positions, pass that to the controller I can return info as:

```
if (Request::get('positions'))
{
    $positions = Request::get('positions');
}
```

Where the positions array could look like
    array:3 [?
    0 => "Analyst"
    1 => "Attorney"
    2 => "Architect"]

```
if($positions)
{
    $users = User::with('skills')
    ->with('skills')
    ->with('positions')
    ->orWhereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
    {
        $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

If I do the same with skills that works as well.

What I need to do is to combine them - especially since I will be adding more related tables into the search function.

I have tried:

```
if(($positions)&&($skills))
{
    $users = User::with('skills')
    ->with('skills')
    ->with('positions')
    ->orWhereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
    {
       $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('skills', function($thisquery) use ($skills)
    {
        $thisquery->whereIn('name', $skills);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

But what I am wanting is something more like

```
$users = User::with('skills')
->with('skills')
->with('positions');
if($skills)
{
    $users->orWhereHas('skills', function($thisquery) use ($skills)
    {
       $thisquery->whereIn('name', $skills);
    });
 }

if($positions)
{
    $users->orWhereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
    {
         $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
    });
}
$users->get();
```

However that doesn't work -just returns empty resultset.

How can I achieve this in an elegant way?

Or is there perhaps a better way to implement a search function - really I am just wanting to filter on certain parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need "and where" condition here. Or where means matching either one or another or both rules. "And where" would only work if both rules match.

So I'd suggest trying this:

```
$users = User::with('skills')
->with('skills')
->with('positions');
if($skills)
{
    $users->whereHas('skills', function($thisquery) use ($skills)
    {
       $thisquery->whereIn('name', $skills);
    });
 }

if($positions)
{
    $users->whereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
    {
         $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
    });
}
$users = $users->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Will play around with variations of "and where" to see the differing results - but this is really great.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself recently.

What I ended up doing was the following:

1. Get all relevant data into an array.
2. Filter that array to match parameter values
3. Return the filtered array.

You can even cache step 1 and recache when you add or update an element.

Go ahead and try an implementation.  If you should get stuck, please update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the input, just so that I understand you a bit better - are you saying I should first get all the skills from the database and then filter on those according to the input array? And then do the same for all positions?

Comment: Before I can answer that, can you tell me how `Users`, `Skills`, and `Positions` are related?

Comment: The users and skills are related in a belongsToMany manner - I have added in info to the question to further clarify the relationship.

So basically a user can have many skills and many skills can belong to many users (and the same for positions).

Comment: Okay.  And what exactly do you intend your filter to do?  In plain business words, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I have a page to find users and want to implement a filter/search function. So if people go to the page they would initially see all users. Then they could select a number of positions and then they would be shown the list of all users with those positions. Going forward they could then also select a number of skills thus showing a list of users who have those positions and those skills.

Comment: It seems like you may have structured your relationships incorrectly.  Based on what you've written, a user has many skills and/or positions.  Skills belong to a user.  Positions belong to a user.  You can then easily do what you are trying to do.  Store all users into an array.  Filter this users arrray by skills and/or positions that match your query.

Comment: I based the relationship structure on a user/role scenario as in "a user with many roles, where the roles are also shared by other users" taken from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent (ManyToMany)

Added in the pivot table structures to the question as that might make more sense!

Comment: Please post your solution once you have found one. In my opinion, this shouldn't be a many to many relationship.  I could be wrong.  But I'd love to see you solve this.