# Query builder structure for related data

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

With my current data , if I create a query in my controller as:

```
$users = User::with('skills')
->with('skills')
->with('positions')
->orWhereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
{
    $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
})
->get();
```

the correct results are returned.

But if I create the query like this:

```
$users = User::with('skills');
$users->with('skills');
$users->with('positions');
$users->orWhereHas('positions', function($thisquery) use ($positions)
{
    $thisquery->whereIn('name', $positions);
})
$users->get();
```

no data is returned.

I would have thought the two would be the same but obviously I am missing some main point  - what is the reason for the differing results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try assigning the `get()` method result like this:

```
$users = $users->get();
```

Chained methods usually work by returning the object as a result. Your `get()` method returns a collection. So you should assign it to some variable in order to somehow use it later.

Also you might wanna consider renaming the `$users` variable although I do the same sometimes as well.

Comment: Will try that "users = $users->get();" suggestion now.

Comment: I'm sure it will work. Also you still left out a semicolon at the end of the same line.

Comment: Great! That works! In fact that structure might also help with my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466257/query-builder-conditional-parameters